# replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript to image for a firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I would like to change every occurrences of certains strings to the image it correspond to.

Exemple:

Before:

> bla bla bla orange bla bla

After:

> bla bla (orange image) in 56px x 56px for exemple.

Replace() use string to string i don't think you can use it for image.

Thank you very much for your time and i hope it was not a duplicate (i searched for 2hours before writing this)

This could be used as ref: https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/emoji-substitution

**(I am not looking to do emoji but images)**

Comment: Replace function can handle emojis, if it's what you intend by images.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to replace with emoji (like ), you don't need to do anything special - that's still just text. But, you can still use [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) if you want to use actual images. You would just replace with HTML and pass the overall string to something like [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). In other words, "orange" would get replaced with `<img class="icon" src="https://..." alt="Orange" />`. For example:

```js
const replaceImages = str => Object.entries({
  orange: {
    src: 'https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/167/167265.svg',
    alt: 'Orange',
  },
  // ...add more replacements here...
}).reduce(
  (result, [key, {src, alt}]) =>
    result.replace(key, `<img src="${src}" alt="${alt}" class="icon" />`),
  str
)

document.querySelector('.js-container').innerHTML =
  replaceImages('bla bla bla orange bla bla')
```

```css
.icon {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, i will try to fully understand how to implement css and html with the manifest file for the firefox addons and i will try it out :)